# Google App engine Backends won't start. How do you trouble shoot backend /_ah/start?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Back ends (all 5) started failing to start for the past 12+ hours. They have been working for the last 8 months without issue.

### I am getting the following error  in the logs.

2012-03-14 15:48:51.977 /_ah/start 302 579ms 0kb instance=0

0.1.0.3 - - [13/Mar/2012:21:48:51 -0700] "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 302......

### "Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404."

This issue is happening to all my backends.

Steps taken:

1) tried to manually stop/start instances in GAE Admin via "backends"

2) rolled back via command line --> appcfyg.py rollback

3) Deleted back-end & previous version  installed a new version and updated backends via command line.

4) installed code as a New application with the same error

5) Triple check code & run locally without an issue

6) Deleted all backend instances & recreated via command line

Is there any other way to trouble shoot or debug to figure out why they have stopped working?

---

Fixed: The issue had to do with the app.yaml.  One of the - url:xxxxx  was causing the issue. It wasn't clear but I removed all and added them back in one at a time testing each as I went. Note: I wasn't retyping but just pasting each section.

I didn't find any major issue so I put it down to white space. The issue has happened on other application & following the same process fixes the issue.

Comment: What happens when you access /_ah/start on your backend manually from an incognito browser (not logged in, cookies removed and so on)? Do you get redirected?

Comment: I get:-

Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.  Does that help identify anything i have missed?

Comment: You included a log statement earlier that says "/_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 302......" and now you get a server error? Does that server error show up in the logs as well?

Comment: Since the response code is a 302, that implies there's a redirect happening somewhere.  Is the script in the backend redirecting to a new page in the application?

Comment: Having this same issue... how can we find out the cause of the redirect?  I thought it was because it was using http vs https...